# Get iCloud name and email swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, icloud, cloudkit

I am using this code to try to get a users iCloud info:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
        self.container.fetchUserRecordID { (recordIDFetched, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let temp = recordIDFetched {
                    let temp2 = CKUserIdentityLookupInfo(userRecordID: temp)
                    let fetchedID = CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation(userIdentityLookupInfos: [temp2])
                    print("\nIDCount")
                    print(fetchedID.userIdentityLookupInfos.count)
                    print("\nIDInfo")
                    print(fetchedID.userIdentityLookupInfos[0].userRecordID ?? "Default RecordID")
                    print("\nIDEmail")
                    print(fetchedID.userIdentityLookupInfos[0].emailAddress ?? "Default Email")
                    print("\nIDPhone")
                    print(fetchedID.userIdentityLookupInfos[0].phoneNumber ?? "Default Phone")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error")
                print(error ?? "Default Error")
            }
            
        }
    }
```

However when I run it it returns:

> IDCount
>
> 1
>
> IDInfo
>
> CKRecordID: 0x6080002303a0; recordName=_06a68abd6423ca06532871a8803f31ee, zoneID=_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**
>
> IDEmail
>
> Default Email
>
> IDPhone
>
> Default Phone

What am I doing wrong?  I know the user is logged into iCloud as it is fetching some data from the server ok - its just this bit that fails.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test my solution right now, but it seems that you need a couple of extra steps.

You shoud invoke the [user identity operation block](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckdiscoveruseridentitiesoperation/1640524-useridentitydiscoveredblock) from the `CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation` class

As `CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation` inherits from CKOperation I think that you should use the [add](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1399215-add) method to *add* the operation to the `CKContainer` in other to execute it.

Comment: I've been having a look but haven't got anything that makes any sense - could you provide some example code?